# How can I discover resources in a Java jar with a wildcard name?

Tags: java, classpath

I want to discover all xml files that my ClassLoader is aware of using a wildcard pattern.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It requires a little trickery, but here's an relevant [blog entry](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2008/01/14/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime/). You first figure out the URLs of the jars, then open the jar and scan its contents. I think you would discover the URLs of all jars by looking for `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'. Directories would be another matter.

Comment: This looks like it would work but would involve a fair amount of searching to get to the file names I want.  I'm thinking that it will be easier to create a file at buid time that contains the files I'm looking at.  This new file would have a known name and could be found using the ClassLoader.

Answer (score 7):

A Spring `ApplicationContext` can do this trivially:

```
 ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationConext.xml");
 Resource[] xmlResources = context.getResources("classpath:/**/*.xml");
```

See [ResourcePatternResolver#getResources](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/support/ResourcePatternResolver.html#getResources(java.lang.String)e), or [ApplicationContext](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html).

Comment: In more recent Spring the pattern won't work. The prefix needs to be `classpath*:` to find the resources inside jars. This at least with a war file and a jar library containing xml files.

Answer (score 6):

```
 List<URL> resources = CPScanner.scanResources(new PackageNameFilter("net.sf.corn.cps.sample"), new ResourceNameFilter("A*.xml"));
```

put the snippet in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.corn</groupId>
    <artifactId>corn-cps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This seems to be one of the easiest solutions.  Latest version is 1.1.7 in maven central, as of 8-20-2014.

Answer (score 1):

A JAR-file is just another ZIP-file, right?

So I suppose you could iterate the jar-files using http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html

I'm thinking something like:

`ZipSearcher searcher = new ZipSearcher(new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("my.jar")));
List xmlFilenames = searcher.search(new RegexFilenameFilter(".xml$"));`

Cheers. Keith.

Answer (score -5):

Well, it is not from within Java, but

`jar -tvf jarname | grep xml$`

will show you all the XMLs in the jar.

Comment: Unfortuneately I need a solution that is within Java.