# Copying directory from jar to the local folder

Tags: java

I have Jar file which includes besides classes - folder with files.
When i run a jar file on the other machine - the aim is to copy files from jar to some folder in that machine.
Structure of jar:

```
/somepackage/
/MyFolder/
```

in code i do something like this:

`copyDirectory("MyFolder", System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\myFolder");`

it works only when i start program, but not outside jar.

Please help me to do it.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386809/copy-a-directory-from-a-jar-file?

Answer (score 0):

You could either manually copy the data out, or, if the data is read-only, just access it directly when needed (simplifying your runtime requirements).

In either case, you'd need to read the contents in the jar file: [How do I read a resource file from a Java jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403256/how-do-i-read-a-resource-file-from-a-java-jar-file)

If you really prefer having things in a local directory, you will need to iterate over all the files you care to have moved out and place them on the disk yourself.