# How to get directory from .jar file into File object?

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource

I have a `.jar` file and at root of them located a folder. How I can read this folder into java `File` class?

Comment: What does it mean to "read a folder into the File class?"

Comment: jar is just a zip with another name and a defined structure - try the zip-streams.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill updated question title. I need to get directory from root of jar into `File` object. I.e. I want to access to directory in root of jar using Java `File` API

Comment: You seem to be looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386809/copy-directory-from-a-jar-file

Comment: File is a wrapper for a file or directory on the file system. It can't be used to access something in a jar file. You should explain us what you want to do with this directory in the jar file. You should also tell us if the jar file is in the classpath or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use File, since this file does not exist independently on the file system. Instead you need getResourceAsStream() to get the contents of the folder, like this:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/FILENAME.TXT");
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```