# Custom plugin can't copy files from jar because protocol is "jar"

Tags: java, plugins, sonarqube

I am developing a plugin for SonarQube, and part of what it must do is copy files from itself to the SonarQube Server's directory.  I am using Apache Commons IO, and have found that `FileUtils.copyDirectory` works wonderfully (after testing it with a main method).
The trouble comes from trying to get the directory of files that I want to copy from the jar of the plugin itself.  I have tried this:

```
public File getSrcDir() {
    URL inputUrl = getClass().getResource("/images");
    File srcDir = FileUtils.toFile(inputUrl);
    System.out.println(srcDir);
    return srcDir;
}
```

When I run it in a main method in my IDE (Eclipse), it prints out `C:\...\[Project Directory]\target\classes\images`
But when I install the plugin into SonarQube as a jar folder in Sonar's "plugins" folder, this method prints out `null`.
I investigated and found that `FileUtils.toFile(URL url)` will return null if the url argument has a protocol other than "File".  So I added this line to my method: `System.out.println(inputUrl.getProtocol());`
Sure enough, in my IDE the protocol is "file", but when my plugin is installed the protocol is "jar"!
I have spent the last day pouring over Stack Overflow and Google trying to find a way to deal with this, but to no avail.
I am willing to try/refactor anything.
All I want to do is make it so that my plugin copies a directory from within its jar to SonarQube's Server.
How can I do this?
In case it's relevant, here is the directory within my project (I want to copy the "images" folder and everything in it):

```
[Project Directory]
    |
    +--/src/main/resources
            |
            +--images
                 |
                 +--profiles
                          |
                          +--awards
                          |    |
                          |    +--Award1.png
                          |    |
                          |    +--Award2.png
                          |
                          +--projects
                               |
                               +--default.png
```

And here is the directory to copy to in the SonarQube server:
`[SONARQUBE_HOME]/war/sonar-server/images`

Comment: A classpath resource is not per definition a local disk file system resource. All with all I believe that you're going in completely the wrong direction as to solving the original problem for which you incorrectly thought that *this* is the right solution. Likely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885201/uploaded-image-only-available-after-refreshing-the-page/8889096#8889096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When resource (in this case images or directory) in classpath coming from jar, it is no longer a physical file

You need to modify the code so that it reads those resources from `Stream` instead of `File`

---

**See**

- [How to read file from classpath from `Stream`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)
- [Get a list of resources from classpath directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory)

Comment: Thanks, this worked, although I had to follow your links a ways and experiment a bunch.  I ended up using code from the answer jabber gave to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386809/copy-directory-from-a-jar-file