# Copying a folder from a .jar file

Tags: java, jar

I created a class called FileCopyFromJAR that has a static method called copy.  This allows me to copy files to outside of the JAR by using getResourceAsStream:

```
 public static void copy(String source,String dest) throws IOException{
    try{
        File sourceFile = new File(source);
        File destFile = new File(dest);
        InputStream in = FileCopyFromJAR.class.getResourceAsStream(source);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buf = new byte[bufferSize];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){
            out.write(buf,0,len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Inside my code, I will call this by doing something like (this assumes test.txt is in the root of my .jar file):

```
FileCopyFromJAR.copy("/test.txt","c:\\test.txt");
```

However, I get a FileNotFoundException if I specify a folder or a file inside a folder.  Both of these return an error:

```
FileCopyFromJAR.copy("folder\test.txt","c:\\test.txt");
FileCopyFromJAR.copy("folder", "c:\\folder");
```

I've also tried using various combinations like /folder\test.txt, etc. but nothing seems to work.  Is there a way to make this work or do I have to use a different method?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question I just had put a bounty on, let me try to find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy directory from a jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386809/copy-directory-from-a-jar-file)

Comment: Have you tried "folder/test.txt"?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, I just made sure.  I tried FileCopyFromJAR.copy("folder\\test.txt", "c:\\test.txt"); I get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Which line give you the file not found exception?

Comment: You should try "folder" + File.pathSeparator + "test.txt"

Comment: @boolean - it says line 25, which is " while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){".  I tried using the File.pathSeparator with the same results.

Comment: Maybe this approach is just wrong.  Any other ideas to extract a folder that is inside a JAR file to outside the JAR?

Comment: Can you post the implementation of FileCopyFromJAR.class.getResourceAsStream(source);?

Comment: @boolean Not sure that I understand.  The entire class FileCopyFromJAR contains only this static method along with a main class I am using to test it.

Comment: To read a JAR as a pseudo-directory, use the methods of java.util.zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!  I broke out my "Core Java Volume 1" 9th edition book and it says "Note that you must always use / separator, regardless of the directory separator on the system that actually stores the resource files." (Horstmann, page 571, chapter 10.1 JAR Files).

So this works:

```
FileCopyFromJAR.copy("/folder/test.txt", "c:\\test12.txt");
```

Hope this helps anyone out there!  It was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

According to the class.getResourceAsStream [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) : "The rules for searching resources associated with a given class are implemented by the defining [class loader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) of the class. "

And then for loader class we have:

Any class name provided as a String parameter to methods in ClassLoader must be a binary name as defined by the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Examples of valid class names include:

```
"java.lang.String"
"javax.swing.JSpinner$DefaultEditor"
"java.security.KeyStore$Builder$FileBuilder$1"
"java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1"
```

Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:

- If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of
  the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
- Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
  modified_package_name/name

**Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').**

So you should use :

```
source = "Package_name" + ".folder.test" //remove the ".txt" from the file
FileCopyFromJAR.class.getResourceAsStream(source);
```

Comment: If I use "test.txt" and it is in the root of the .jar file, it works?  In any case, when I called the static method using FileCopyFromJAR.copy("folder.test","c:\\test12.txt"); I still get a NullPointerException.  This passes in folder.test to "source" in the static copy method.

Comment: @Trinculo there... it should work with the package name.