# Load multiple dependent libraries with JNA

Tags: java, dll, jna

Is there a way in JNA to load multiple dependent libraries with Java?

I usually use `Native.loadLibrary(...)` to load one DLL. But I guess its not working this way because I assign this function call to the instance member.

Comment: Multiple native libraries or multiple JNA library mappings from the same native library?

Comment: Multiple native libraries. They are completley different. One of the DLLs is depending somehow on the other.(I've got this from the Dependency Walker)

Comment: Just make sure you load the one _without_ dependencies on the other first, either via JNA or System.loadLibrary().

Comment: This is in fact the problem. Loading the DLLs with System.loadLibrary() causes an UnsatisfiedLinkError when I try to call some functions.  And I dont know how to load multiple Libraries with JNA because I there is no static initializer allowed. Or am I totally wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say I have library `foo` and library `bar`.  `bar` has a dependency on `foo`; it also has a dependency on `baz`, which we are *not* mapping with JNA:

```
public class Foo {
    public static final boolean LOADED;
    static {
        Native.register("foo");
        LOADED = true;
    }
    public static native void call_foo();
}

public class Bar {
    static {
        // Reference "Foo" so that it is loaded first
        if (Foo.LOADED) {
            System.loadLibrary("baz");
            // Or System.load("/path/to/libbaz.so")
            Native.register("bar");
        }
    }
    public static native void call_bar();
}
```

The call to `System.load/loadLibrary` will only be necessary if `baz` is neither on your library load path (`PATH`/`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, for windows/linux respectively) nor in the same directory as `bar` (windows only).

**EDIT**

You can also do this via interface mapping:

```
public interface Foo extends Library {
    Foo INSTANCE = (Foo)Native.loadLibrary("foo");
}
public interface Bar extends Library {
    // Reference Foo prior to instantiating Bar, just be sure
    // to reference the Foo class prior to creating the Bar instance
    Foo FOO = Foo.INSTANCE;
    Bar INSTANCE = (Bar)Native.loadLibrary("bar");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its easier than I thought it will be.

Comment: So this assumes Bar is dependent on Foo? Is there a way to load them if they're both dependent on each other?

Comment: Figure out how to do it with system calls first, and then do those calls in JNA.

Answer (score 1):

**Loading lib transient dependencies with JNA from JAR Resources.**

My resources folder res:

```
res/
`-- linux-x86-64
    |-- libapi.so
    |-- libdependency.so
```

-

```
MyApiLibrary api = (MyApiLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("libapi.so", MyApiLibrary.class, options);
```

API Explodes:
**Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error loading shared library libdependency.so: No such file or directory**

Can be solved by loading dependencies beforehand by hand:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;

Native.loadLibrary("libdependency.so", Library.class);
MyApiLibrary api = (MyApiLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("libapi.so", MyApiLibrary.class, options);
```

Basically you have to build dependency tree in reverse, by hand, by yourself.

---

I recommend setting

```
java -Djna.debug_load=true -Djna.debug_load.jna=true
```

Furthermore, setting **jna.library.path** to Resource has no effect, because JNA extracts to filesystem, then it loads lib. Lib on filesystem can NOT access other libs within jar.

> Context class loader classpath. Deployed native libraries may be
>   installed on the classpath under ${os-prefix}/LIBRARY_FILENAME, where
>   ${os-prefix} is the OS/Arch prefix returned by
>   Platform.getNativeLibraryResourcePrefix(). If bundled in a jar file,
>   the resource will be extracted to jna.tmpdir for loading, and later
>   removed (but only if jna.nounpack is false or not set).

[Javadoc](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html)

RTFM and happy coding. JNA v.4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation, dealing with multiplatform and several dependent libraries, **but needing to load only one**. Here is my take.

Suppose you get a set 32/64 win/linux libraries with dependencies.
Suppose you only need to have a JNA binding for `libapi`

You'll need to organize them into your jar like this:

```
linux-x86-64
    |-- libapi.so
    |-- libdependency.so
linux-x86
    |-- libapi.so
    |-- libdependency.so
win32-x86-64
    |-- libapi.dll
    |-- libdependency.dll
win32-x86
    |-- libapi.dll
    |-- libdependency.dll
```

You can:

- determine if executing from a JAR file (avoids performing the operation when executing from your favorite IDE ; see [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file))
- use JNA to determine your current executing platform
- extract *all appropriate library files* into java temp folder (using elements from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58318009/7237062 (or related answers) should do the trick)
- Tell JNA to look into the newly created temp folder
- and voilà !
- missing in code example is the directory cleanup at application shutdown, but I leave that to you

The main part should look like that:

MainClass.java

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.InvalidPathException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import com.sun.jna.Platform;

public class MainClass {
    private static final String JAVA_IO_TMPDIR = "java.io.tmpdir";
    private static final String TEMP_DIR = System.getProperty(JAVA_IO_TMPDIR);
    private static final String JNA_LIBRARY_PATH = "jna.library.path";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
        // path management here maybe suboptimal ... feel free to improve
        // from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file
        URL current_jar_dir = Overview.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        Path jar_path = Paths.get(current_jar_dir.toURI());
        String folderContainingJar = jar_path.getParent().toString();

        ResourceCopy r = new ResourceCopy(); // class from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58318009/7237062 
        Optional<JarFile> jar = r.jar(MainClass.class);
        if (jar.isPresent()) {
            try {
            System.out.println("JAR detected");
            File target_dir = new File(TEMP_DIR);
            System.out.println(String.format("Trying copy from %s %s to %s", jar.get().getName(), Platform.RESOURCE_PREFIX, target_dir));
            // perform dir copy
            r.copyResourceDirectory(jar.get(), Platform.RESOURCE_PREFIX, target_dir);
            // add created folders to JNA lib loading path
            System.setProperty(JNA_LIBRARY_PATH, target_dir.getCanonicalPath().toString());             
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // TODO: handle exception ?
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO JAR");
        }
        // ...
    }
```

ResourceCopy.java (copy here for completeness; taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58318009)

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
/**
 * A helper to copy resources from a JAR file into a directory. source :
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/58318009
 */
public final class ResourceCopy {

    /**
     * URI prefix for JAR files.
     */
    private static final String JAR_URI_PREFIX = "jar:file:";

    /**
     * The default buffer size.
     */
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 8 * 1024;

    /**
     * Copies a set of resources into a temporal directory, optionally
     * preserving the paths of the resources.
     * 
     * @param preserve
     *            Whether the files should be placed directly in the directory
     *            or the source path should be kept
     * @param paths
     *            The paths to the resources
     * @return The temporal directory
     * @throws IOException
     *             If there is an I/O error
     */
    public File copyResourcesToTempDir(final boolean preserve, final String... paths) throws IOException {
        final File parent = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        File directory;
        do {
            directory = new File(parent, String.valueOf(System.nanoTime()));
        } while (!directory.mkdir());
        return this.copyResourcesToDir(directory, preserve, paths);
    }

    /**
     * Copies a set of resources into a directory, preserving the paths and
     * names of the resources.
     * 
     * @param directory
     *            The target directory
     * @param preserve
     *            Whether the files should be placed directly in the directory
     *            or the source path should be kept
     * @param paths
     *            The paths to the resources
     * @return The temporal directory
     * @throws IOException
     *             If there is an I/O error
     */
    public File copyResourcesToDir(final File directory, final boolean preserve, final String... paths)
            throws IOException {
        for (final String path : paths) {
            final File target;
            if (preserve) {
                target = new File(directory, path);
                target.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            } else {
                target = new File(directory, new File(path).getName());
            }
            this.writeToFile(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path), target);
        }
        return directory;
    }

    /**
     * Copies a resource directory from inside a JAR file to a target directory.
     * 
     * @param source
     *            The JAR file
     * @param path
     *            The path to the directory inside the JAR file
     * @param target
     *            The target directory
     * @throws IOException
     *             If there is an I/O error
     */
    public void copyResourceDirectory(final JarFile source, final String path, final File target) throws IOException {
        final Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = source.entries();
        final String newpath = String.format("%s/", path);
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            final JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            if (entry.getName().startsWith(newpath) && !entry.isDirectory()) {
                final File dest = new File(target, entry.getName().substring(newpath.length()));
                final File parent = dest.getParentFile();
                if (parent != null) {
                    parent.mkdirs();
                }
                this.writeToFile(source.getInputStream(entry), dest);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The JAR file containing the given class.
     * 
     * @param clazz
     *            The class
     * @return The JAR file or null
     * @throws IOException
     *             If there is an I/O error
     */
    public Optional<JarFile> jar(final Class<?> clazz) throws IOException {
        final String path = String.format("/%s.class", clazz.getName().replace('.', '/'));
        final URL url = clazz.getResource(path);
        Optional<JarFile> optional = Optional.empty();
        if (url != null) {
            final String jar = url.toString();
            final int bang = jar.indexOf('!');
            if (jar.startsWith(ResourceCopy.JAR_URI_PREFIX) && bang != -1) {
                optional = Optional.of(new JarFile(jar.substring(ResourceCopy.JAR_URI_PREFIX.length(), bang)));
            }
        }
        return optional;
    }

    /**
     * Writes an input stream to a file.
     * 
     * @param input
     *            The input stream
     * @param target
     *            The target file
     * @throws IOException
     *             If there is an I/O error
     */
    private void writeToFile(final InputStream input, final File target) throws IOException {
        final OutputStream output = Files.newOutputStream(target.toPath());
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[ResourceCopy.BUFFER_SIZE];
        int length = input.read(buffer);
        while (length > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            length = input.read(buffer);
        }
        input.close();
        output.close();
    }

}
```